# nodejs returning raw special characters on linux bash

Tags: node.js, string, special-characters

when in node shell, if I type *'hello\nworld'*, output is displayed in the same way, literally. That is not the case in, e.g. firefox console, where a newline is being processed to break the line. If I use `console.log()`, the character is processed as expected. Same goes for other special characters.

I know it seems too trivial to even be worth posting a question, but I'm wondering if I need to check some nodejs settings on my local setup like, for example, git line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Either in node terminal or on browsers, Whatever your write and enter, the first thing you would see is the `return` stuff of that executed code.
When you just add `'hello\nworld'` (any string), basically you are just creating a string without being assigned to any variable so it will just create and return the same thing.

In simple words - When you write :
`const name = 'punkuotukas'`
The string `'punkuotukas'` is created and returned, and the returned stuff is caught with the variable `name` and holds it now. And hence now the `'punkuotukas'` is stored in the variable `name`.
Now,
What if we don't have `const name =` ? At that time, the string will be returned as it is.

Now let's consider the case of `console.log` this function logs the data which we pass to it.
And while logging the data, it will consider the special characters, escape characters and do the needful.

But why is not happening with normal `'punkuotukas'` ?
Because we are not logging anything here, and it is just throwing the returned stuff ( the string ) instead of log ( most importantly, \n is now the part of string your created ).
Hence the special characters, escape sequences etc work with console functions not with just strings.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I understood correctly:
String literals will always return string as it was created (if I include '\n' into a string literal, it will be returned as '\n' - not as a line break)?
but then, I cannot agree regarding browser console. I've tried just now on firefox: it does process the '\n' in string (without console.log()) and returns a string in 2 separate lines.